# Rescue from single resource exceptions in Rails index action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For the show action, returning a 500 error on uncaught exceptions is fine, but for the index action, it would be helpful if a single bad resource didn't cause the whole request to fail. Is there a way to rescue from those exceptions and return the rest of the resources along with a list of errors?

*Details*: I'm using RABL to render JSON templates like this (but I think the solution is likely general rather than specific to this):

```
# app/controllers/happenings_controller.rb
def index
  @happenings = current_person.happenings
end

# app/views/happening/index.json.rabl
collection @happenings
extends 'happenings/show'

# app/views/happening/show.json.rabl
object @happening
attributes :id, :name, :description
node :creator, if: lambda { |s| s.creator? } do |s|
  # !!! This is where an exception on a single resource was blowing up the whole request
  partial("people/show", :object => s.creator)
end
```

Comment: Define "bad resource"?  What does the index action look like in the controller?

Comment: Bad resource is one which rendering throws an exception. I'm using RABL templates to automatically render the show template for each resource, but could manually do this, so I don't think the solution has to take this into account. Details added to post.

Answer (score 0):

Sure! Just rescue the exception.

So, this answer probably does not help you at all, but it is just because you did not provide any meaningful description about your problem.

It all depends on where your errors occur. Do you want to rescue from database queries, rendering errors, environment problems?

Depending on the cause of the error there are different solutions like monkey-patching rabl, a simple rescue in your controller or some middleware handling the error.

Comment: It's rendering error I want to handle. So that probably means either monkey-patching rabl or writing an explicit loop in the index action with a rescue+next inside the loop.